Nomenclature for Application dependency
Assume that this command invokes an application from the MacOS terminal command line:
/Applications/Matlab_R2020a.app/bin/matlab

The terminal then is no longer able to accept commands and MATLAB is dependent (i.e. will terminate if the terminal console is closed).   What is this dependency called and how can the application be started so that it will be "independent"?   That is, closing the terminal will not close the application?

This question is similar to: How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru the question here asks about the relation and how you call it; it's different in that part. For the second half of the question, "how can it be started so that it will be independent", I'd agree, this is a duplicate. But the first half is different.

Yes, that's why questions should be focused. Either it gets edited to be more focused, or closed as too broad, or as duplicate.

The dependency would be that matlab is spawned as a child process of your shell, which in turn is a child process of your terminal emulator application.
Now, that's not what makes matlab exit when your shell exits/gets terminated.
The shell itself has a hook that notices that it's about to end, and will send a "hangup" (as in hanging up your phone) signal, SIGHUP, to the process(es) it spawned. Unless your process (i.e., matlab) itself has installed a specific handler for that signal that stops that, or explicitly said it'll ignore that signal, it will exit.
So the relationship between matlab and your shell is parental, but the thing that quits matlab is an explicit intervention by the shell.
Romeo's answer shows how to circumvent that: instead of launching matlab, you can launch the nohup program, which in itself doesn't do much – it only declares that itself ignores the hangup signal, and launches the program you specify as argument, replacing itself. (It also bends standard input and output if desired.)

@marcusmiller. An exemplary explanation of the why of things: thank you

To run command and deattach it from terminal the usual UNIX/Linux practice is to use something like:
nohup <command> >out_log 2>err_log &

nohup deattach it from terminal
& put it in background
(of course replace <command> with the name of your command, like /Applications/Matlab_R2020a.app/bin/matlab)
The construction >out_log store in file out_log the output of the program, sent to STDOUT. The construction 2>err_log store in file err_log the output of the program, sent to STDERR. This is good practice to keep this information and to store it in separate file in case of need for some debug, investigation, etc.

Thank you, Please elaborate as to why >out_log 2>err_log  is in the template?

@gatorback, check my edited answer

That's a good start.
